# exact foreach loop to access ragridview row

Tags: c#, datatable, radgridview

Help !!!

I'm having a radgridview, i want to get the data from radgrid into the datatable. In the below code im able to get the column name (1st foreach loop) in the datatabe. But i'm not at all getting how fetch row from radgrid into datatable row.

**CODE**

```
  DataTable dtRecords = new DataTable();
  foreach (Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn col in OverallExposureGrid.Columns)
  {
      DataColumn colString = new DataColumn(col.UniqueName);
      dtRecords.Columns.Add(colString);
  }
  foreach ( **---- wat should i put here ---**)//loop thr each row in radgrid
        {
            DataRow dr = dtRecords.NewRow();
            foreach (Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn col in OverallExposureGrid.Columns) //loops through each column in RadGrid
                 dr[col.UniqueName] = row[col.UniqueName].Text;//error 
                dtRecords.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

**XAML CODE**:

```
            <telerik:RadGridView  telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Expression_Dark" x:Name="OverallExposureGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding RegionSales, Mode=TwoWay}" ShowGroupPanel="False" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="444">
                        <telerik:RadGridView.ColumnGroups>
                            <telerik:GridViewColumnGroup Block.IsHyphenationEnabled="True" Name="commentGroup" Header="Notes" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GroupStyle}"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewColumnGroup Block.IsHyphenationEnabled="True" Name="BlankGroup" Header="" />

                        </telerik:RadGridView.ColumnGroups>
                        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Ticker" UniqueName="Ticker"  TextBlock.FontWeight="ExtraBold" ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup"  DataMemberBinding="{Binding CompnayTicker, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" TextBlock.FontWeight="ExtraBold" IsVisible="{Binding CompanyNameVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Company Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyName, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding DomicileCountryVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Domicile Country" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DomicileCountry, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding GICS1Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="GICS Sector Level 1" DataMemberBinding="{Binding GICSL1, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding GICS2Visibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="GICS Sector Level 2" DataMemberBinding="{Binding GICSL2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Left"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding MarketCapVisibility, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Mkt Cap" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MKTCap, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="True" Header="LRY" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LRY, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding EuropeVisibilityFullView}" UniqueName="Europe" Header="Europe" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding EuropeSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding UKVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="UK" Header="UK" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.UK, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding EURxUKVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="EURxUK" Header="EUR x UK" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.EURxUK, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding FranceVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="France" Header="France" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.France, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding GermanyVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Germany"  Header="Germany" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Germany, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding GreeceVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Greece" Header="Greece" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Greece, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding ItalyVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Italy" Header="Italy" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Italy, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding IrelandVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Ireland" Header="Ireland" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Ireland, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding PortugalVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Portugal" Header="Portugal" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Portugal, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding SpainVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Spain" Header="Spain" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Europe.Spain, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding CEEMEAVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}"  Header="CEEMEA" UniqueName="CEEMEA" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CEEMEASales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding RussiaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Russia" Header="Russia" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CEEMEA.Russia, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding MideastVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Mid East" Header="Mid East" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CEEMEA.MidEast, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding AfricaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Africa" Header="Africa" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CEEMEA.Africa, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding OtherCEEEMAVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Other CEEMEA" Header="Other CEEMEA" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding CEEMEA.OtherCEEMEA, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding NorthAmericaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="North America" Header="North America" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding NorthAmericaSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding LatamVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Latam" Header="Latam" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LatamSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding MexicoVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Mexico" Header="Mexico" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Latam.Mexico, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding BrazilVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Brazil" Header="Brazil" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Latam.Brazil, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding OtherLatamVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Other Latam" Header="Other Latam" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Latam.OtherLatam, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding JapanVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Japan" Header="Japan" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding JapanSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding AuNzVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Au/NZ" Header="AU/NZ" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding AuNZSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding AsiaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Asia" Header="Asia" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding AsiaSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding ChinaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="China" Header="China" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Asia.China, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding IndiaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="India" Header="India" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Asia.India, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding KoreaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Korea" Header="Korea" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Asia.Korea, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding OtherAsiaVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Other Asia" Header="Other Asia" HeaderCellStyle="{StaticResource HeaderStyleCountries}" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Asia.OtherAsia, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding OtherVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Other" Header="Other" DataMemberBinding="{Binding OtherSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" IsVisible="{Binding MixedVisibilityFullView, Mode=TwoWay}" UniqueName="Mixed" Header="Mixed" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MixedSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <!--<telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" Header="Total" DataMemberBinding="{Binding TotalSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>-->
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup" Header="Developed" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DevelopedSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn ColumnGroupName="BlankGroup"  Header="Emerging" DataMemberBinding="{Binding EmergingSales, Converter={StaticResource formatCellConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" TextAlignment="Right"/>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Other" ColumnGroupName="commentGroup" DataMemberBinding="{Binding OtherNotes, Mode=TwoWay}"  MaxWidth="180" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>

                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Mixed" ColumnGroupName="commentGroup" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MixedNotes, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxWidth="180" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="200"/>

                        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

**I dont want to get the data from  item source, the data into the datatable to be from current data form radgrid**. m a newbie for this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apply the DataLoaded event to your RadGridView. you will get the sorted items in the ItemsContaiserGenerator.

you can get the items in it by using

```
List<class> variable= new List<class>();

for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
           (class)row = (class)sender.Items[i];
           {
               variable.Add(row);
           }
       }
```